# Deciphering Swift examples

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array, closures

As I am learning swift I have been given some examples that I cannot decipher. Could someone please help me understand the following block particularly without all of the closure shorthand.

```
        let arrayElement = [Bool](repeating: false, count: 10)
    var before = [[Bool]](repeating: arrayElement, count:10)
   // i is the columns and j is the rows
    for i in 0 ..< arrayElement.count {
        for j in 0 ..< before.count {
            if arc4random_uniform(3) == 1 {
                var row = before[j]
                row[i] = true
                before[j] = row

            }
        }
    }

    let numberOfTrue = (0 ..< before.count).reduce(0) { (accum, row) in
        return accum + before[row].filter { $0 }.count

    }
```

Comment: In a nutshell, the first part initializes a 2-d array of bools randomly with true or false.  The second part with the closures counts the number of trues using reduce and filter.

Comment: A useful explanation is easier if we understand where you are confused. What do you think this code does, where do you get stuck, and what specific questions do you have?

Comment: I am having a problem figuring out all of the closure shorthand of the numberOfTrue constant